# What sort of information do I need to send a bug report to nouveau developers?

Tags: 10.04, xorg, nouveau, ppc

I'm aware that nouveau on PPC is "known to work" more than "rigorously tested" but I'm having issues with certain OpenGL 2D programs (not 3D) where the [colors are completely off](http://suen.educ.psu.edu/~bkemp/pink.png).

While it could be an issue w/ the application (note Alpha in title), SDL works well, if not a bit slow.

What information should I capture in order to send upstream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [/Bugs wiki page](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/Bugs) on the Nouveau wiki at freedesktop.org says:

> - Attach **complete, unfiltered, untrimmed kernel log** from boot up to
>     the problem, and a complete X log if
>     the problem manifests with X
> - Please, **do not compress files** you attach to bug reports, especially
>     plain text files such as logs, unless
>     the file is so huge bugzilla refuses
>     to take it. Gzipping files makes
>     taking a quick look impossible
> - Make sure the **mime-type** of text files really is set to
>     text/plain, and not e.g.
>     application/octet-stream. This makes
>     life a little easier for people
>     reading bug reports. The point is to
>     let people read text files directly in
>     a web browser.

Answer (score 3):

As the nouveau developers are quite busy, I would highly recommend treating the issue as an application bug and talking with the app developers first, to rule out that it is just a bug in your app.  Or, see if you can reproduce it in a second GL app.

If/when you do forward to the nouveau guys, attach the following to your upstream bug report:

(a) Screenshot / photo showing problem

(b) /var/log/Xorg.0.log

(c) /etc/X11/xorg.conf (if any)

(d) Your ~/.drirc (if any)

(e) output of `sudo dmesg`

Also, specify if this is a regression, and if it is make sure to itemize what changed on your system (hardware, software versions, particular updates, etc.) when you started noticing it.

Answer (score 2):

Try running your application in the terminal and send in the output:

```
Application > output.txt
```

Also you can send them the ID of your card, your xorg.conf, and sdlerr.txt (should appear in the working directory if you run the program from the terminal). I'm not sure if they should need any further information. What you could also do (**NB Risky**): is to try the updated drivers from the x development ppa (find it in ubuntu-tweak) and see if you get the same results on that one. That would tell you if it is fixed upstream.